# Converting epoch to date & time with time zone in xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How do I convert epoch time to date & time based on time zone in xslt 2.0 ?

For example, epoch time 1212497304 converts to

GMT: Tue, 03 Jun 2008 12:48:24 GMT
time zone: martes, 03 de junio de 2008 14:48:24 GMT+2

This is because of the Daylight Saving Time (DST): in many countries there is one hour more in summer, during some dates that varies each year.

For example, it is supposed that this instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select=" format-dateTime(xs:dateTime('2013-07-07T23:08:00+00:00'), '[D] [MNn] [Y] [h]:[m01][PN,*-2] [Z] ([C])', 'en', 'AD', 'IST') "/>
```

would calculate the given GMT date event into Indian Standard Time (IST) with Gregorian Calendar (AD) but it just prints:

```
7 July 2013 11:08PM +00:00 (Gregorian)
```

So it does not shift the time zone.
To shift the time zone we must use:

```
adjust-dateTime-to-timezone
```

But this function accepts only a duration in number of hours/minutes, not a TimeZone so that the processor determines if there is DST or not.

Any advise, please

Comment: I think you mean *Unix time*, not *epoch time* (which is a meaningless expression). In any case, if all you have is GMT time, you cannot tell what the local time was without consulting the [Olson database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). I don't know how one would go about that, using only XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This is not really the answer to the actual question asked, which was how to get the correct local time, respecting its timezone, but I'll still leave it here since it might be usefull to someone.

<s>Because epoch is just seconds past since unix time you can just add it to unix time like this:</s>

Unix time is the number of seconds elapsed since the epoch of midnight 1970-01-01, you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1212497304S')"
    />
```

This will give you the correct xs:dateTime of 2008-06-03T12:48:24

Put into a function:

```
<xsl:function name="fn:epochToDate">
    <xsl:param name="epoch"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dayTimeDuration" select="concat('PT',$epoch,'S')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') + xs:dayTimeDuration($dayTimeDuration)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: "*epoch is just seconds past since unix time*" Nitpick: Unix time is the number of seconds elapsed since the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) of midnight 1970-01-01. Not the other way round. Anyway, I think this question is (or was) about converting Unix (i.e. GMT) time into *local* time.

Comment: @michael.hor257k well yeah your absolutely right, that was written rather quickly...and for the actual question, well that happens when you read half the post and have the answer to that half allready lying around ...I'll update my answer, but leave it here, I think someone might still find it usefull :)